# Downloadable product event if someone click on the document (pdf) included

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer

I need to trigger an event if an user click a downloadable product, i mean the document (pdf, word, etc...) included because i need my customer read those documents, and after that i need to do some action
Is there any event dispatched by downloadable product or i need to create a custom event?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

When you check on [`linkAction()`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/controllers/DownloadController.php#L155)(This action is responsible when you click on download) from

`app\code\core\Mage\Downloadable\controllers\DownloadController.php` . From this action, I can say that there is no event used by `Magento`. I think you need to overwrite this action to dispatch your event to perform some action.

Comment: Your suggestion is right but dispatching the event inside linkAction() doesn't work. Instead it work if for example i dispatch the event inside getBasePath() in app\code\core\Mage\Downloadable\Model\Sample.php

Comment: Could you please post your code which you have written for dispatch event @Ivan

Comment: accept the answer If you find It helpful @Ivan